# how to use session in sinatra post request?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am setting session in "/login" post request so when i trying to access that session in other api the session value will be nil.

```
post '/login', :provides => :json do        
    params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
    uname =  params["username"]
    session[:username] = random_string
    return session[:username]
end

get '/list' do
    puts session[:username]
end
```

"/list" call print "nil" in command line

What is the solution to use that session outside this post request once it set by "/login"?

Comment: How are you making the requests? With a browser or some other tool?

Comment: using command line: curl -X POST -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}' http://localhost:4567/login

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking year curl request is a single session, and won't persist to the following get request?

Comment: You need to store and resend cookies if you want sessions to work. I think you need to look at the `-b` and `-c` options to `curl`.